# How to prevent HTML tag rendering in a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, html, json, datatables

I have a JSON file in which I am trying to add HTML tags, inline styles and script tags and passing the data to the table. DataTables is actually rendering all the HTML tags in the JSON.

How do I prevent this from happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="example" class="display table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>        
    </table>
    
    </body>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var myData = 
 [
    {
      "name": "<p>Jack</p>",
      "age": 29      
    },
    {
      "name": "<b><i>Madame Uppercut</i></b>",
      "age": 39
    },
    {
      "name": "<h4 style='color:red'>Eternal Flame</h4>",
      "age": 45
    }
  ];
            $('#example').DataTable({
                data: myData,
                "columns": [{"data":"name"},{"data":"age"}]
            });
        });         
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the string which contains HTML tags and parse it using jQuery's [parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) function.

- Wrap the string in a `<span>` element, to ensure there is *always* a HTML container. This handles situations where the data string may contain no HML tags, or only HTML tags in the body of the string (not at the start).
- Access the data you need using [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

All of this logic can be handled in a DataTables [column render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function.

A runnable demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var myData = [{
      "name": "<p>Jack</p>",
      "age": 29
    },
    {
      "name": "<b><i>Madame Uppercut</i></b>",
      "age": 39
    },
    {
      "name": "<h4 style='color:red'>Eternal Flame</h4>",
      "age": 45
    },
    {
      "name": "Normal Name No HTML",
      "age": 45
    },
    {
      "name": "Not <b>Normal</b> Name - HTML inside the string",
      "age": 45
    }
  ];

  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: myData,
    columns: [{
        data: "name",
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          let node = $.parseHTML( '<span>' + data + '</span>' )[0];
          return node.innerText;
        }
      },
      {
        data: "age"
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="example" class="display table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

This assumes the HTML provided in the data is always well-formed.

I have not tested any strings which contain HTML comments (`<!-- -->`). I assume that is not relevant here.

---

**Update**

> it fails in these 2 scenarios, 1. HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) 2. `<script>alert("test")</script>`

For a **comment** such as this:

```
 not a comment<!-- comment -->
```

then any text inside the comment will be ignored, but other content will be displayed in the table. If there is no content outside of the comment then you will see a blank cell in the DataTable.

(The question doesn't mention HTML comments, or what is expected to happens when they are encountered.)

For a **script** such as this:

```
<script>alert("test")</script>
```

There are 2 issues here:

(a) You cannot nest `<script>` tags inside other `<script>` tags. In the approach in the question, your test data (`var myData`) is already inside a `<script>` tag. One way to handle this is to encode the `<` and `>` characters:

```
&ltscript&gtalert("test");&lt/script&gt
```

(b) The second issue is that the `"` characters in `"test"` are nested inside the JSON string. You can change them to `'` single quotes, or you can similarly encode them. Here is the single quotes approach:

```
   &ltscript&gtalert('test');&lt/script&gt
```

**WARNING**: Doing (b) means the script will actually run when the DataTable is loaded - and that is almost certainly a very bad (maybe even dangerous) idea. I have to wonder why there are JavaScript scripts inserted into the source data in the first place.

---

**Update 2**

If you want a quick and dirty fix (while you investigate how to correctly cleanse the unwanted & untrusted user-input at source), you can do this:

```js
render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
  return data.replace( /<.*?>/g, '' );
}
```

This is [how DataTables itself strips HTML tags from input](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/1eddf57e55486c9e69581f14f77a2c3cd58b43f4/js/core/core.internal.js#L201), for example, for sorting data which uses the HTML [column type](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type).

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response.
Your solution is working fine for usual HTML tags.
but it fails in these 2 scenarios,
1. HTML comments (<!-- -->) 
2. <script>alert("test")</script>

Comment: (1) Fails how? (2) What do you expect in each case?

Comment: 1. It comments/hides the data 2. Alert is rendering when we add <script> tag

Comment: The simple answer would be: Don't place content in comments if you want that content to be displayed in the table (or maybe clarify _why_ you are using comments and _why_ you want the content to be displayed). You can edit the question.

Comment: Similarly for scripts - why are you doing this - and where is this data coming from? This sounds potentially dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. Your effort is very much appreciated!
In our project, we are using datatable to list out the data added by the users. One crazy user added a <script>alert("test")</script> tag inside an input text field and saved. 
The script is retrieved from the DB and rendered in the data table (alerting "test"). Now the user raised a ticket that the application is vulnerable. I know it looks funny, but this is the truth 

Comment: That is a completely different problem, I think. You should be sanitizing the user-provided data at its source, not at this step.

Comment: What your user did was not crazy at all.  It was done to show the dangers your app is vulnerable to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248811/discussion-between-jagadheesh-and-andrewjames).